# Что значит "вынести зависимости вынести в npm или bower"?

Tags: npm, bower

Не понимаю смысл этого выражения, поясните.

Comment: Значит не скачивать руками jquery и bootstrap и не складывать их в виде файлов в папки js и css на сайте, а установить с помощью менеджера зависимостей: npm или bower, и подключать их оттуда, куда менеджер поставил.